# Redirect domain to subdirectory and rewrite the URL path

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I realize that similar questions have been asked many times, but so far I haven't found a solution for my specific case.

My girlfriend has an older blog that was built using Joomla. The domain is currently pointed at the root directory which is where the Joomla site lives. Recently, she asked to switch to Wordpress, which I set up in a subdirectory of the root named "new". So, example.com points to the root and is the Joomla website. example.com/new is where I installed Wordpress, and how she accessed the new site while working on the design and content.

She's now ready for the WP site to go live, and the Joomla site is obsolete. My initial thought was to delete the Joomla files from the root and copy the WP files from the /new/ directory to the root, but I wasn't sure if that would work.

My next thought was to avoid deleting files and instead redirect and rewrite. If I go this route I need requests for example.com to go to example.com/new, example.com/page to example.com/new/page, and also rewrite the URL path so example.com/new becomes example.com, and example.com/new/page becomes example.com/page.

So far, I've tried several combinations of rewrite and redirect rules in the root htaccess, but none have gotten the job done. The rules I have tried so far include:

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$   
# RewriteRule !^new/ new%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [NC,L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# RewriteRule ^(/)?$ new/index.php [L]
```

I would surely appreciate advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Archive the old website and save it somewhere. Delete everything and move your WP in root. No need to overcomplicating since she wont use the joomla anyway. In case you want to refer some content from the old website load it in sub dir as you did with WP and so on. For WP you will need to fix permalinks and .htaccess file since prob is pointing to /new dir .

Comment: Alternative approach would be just to point your domain to root/new dir and no redirection will be needed. If you insist on doing it with htaccess check this article by WP - https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

Comment: Thanks @Snuffy. I had a feeling I was overcomplicating it. I think I'll give the alt suggestion a whirl. If that works then it won't take much to manually edit internal links and remove the /new path.